# List<T> FirstOrDefault() bad performance - is dictionary possible in this case?

Tags: c#, linq, performance, linq-to-sql, list

I have set of 'codes' Z that are valid in a certain time period.

Since I need them a lot of times in a large loop (million+) and every time I have to lookup the corresponding code I cache them in a List<>. After finding the correct codes, i'm inserting (using SqlBulkCopy) a  million rows.

I lookup the id with the following code (`l_z` is a `List<T>`)

```
var z_fk = (from z in l_z
            where z.CODE == lookupCode &&
                  z.VALIDFROM <= lookupDate &&
                  z.VALIDUNTIL >= lookupDate 
            select z.id).SingleOrDefault();
```

In other situations I have used a Dictionary with superb performance, but in those cases I only had to lookup the id based on the code.

But now with searching on the combination of fields, I am stuck.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a Dictionary that stores a List of items per lookup code - `Dictionary<string, List<Code>>` (assuming that lookup code is a string and the objects are of type Code).

Then when you need to query based on `lookupDate`, you can run your query directly off of `dict[lookupCode]`:

```
var z_fk = (from z in dict[lookupCode]
            where z.VALIDFROM <= lookupDate &&
                  z.VALIDUNTIL >= lookupDate 
            select z.id).SingleOrDefault();
```

Then just make sure that whenever you have a new Code object, that it gets added to the `List<Code>` collection in the `dict` corresponding to the `lookupCode` (and if one doesn't exist, then create it).

Comment: Used this approach and it's much faster, so for the time I am happy now. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I was doing a FirstOrDefault in a foreach loop on a large set of objects. The Dictionary approach made it blazingly fast!

Answer (score 4):

A simple improvement would be to use...

```
//in initialization somewhere
ILookup<string, T> l_z_lookup = l_z.ToLookup(z=>z.CODE);

//your repeated code:
var z_fk = (from z in lookup[lookupCode]
            where z.VALIDFROM <= lookupDate && z.VALIDUNTIL >= lookupDate 
            select z.id).SingleOrDefault();
```

You could further use a more complex, smarter data structure storing dates in sorted fashion and use a binary search to find the id, but this may be sufficient.  Further, you speak of `SqlBulkCopy` - if you're dealing with a database, perhaps you can execute the query on the database, and then simply create the appropriate index including columns CODE, VALIDUNTIL and VALIDFROM.

I generally prefer using a `Lookup` over a `Dictionary` containing `Lists` since it's trivial to construct and has a cleaner API (e.g. when a key is not present).

Comment: I have used the dictionary with the list now and it works like a dream. Perhaps afterwards I will try the ILookUp. How would it compare in performance?

Comment: It would be pretty much identical.  An ILookup is conceptually simply a Dictionary containing lists - it's possible there's a few slight savings by avoiding safety checks for two API's vs just one, but perhaps it's less tuned too - either way, I doubt it's relevant for any application.

Answer (score 1):

This to me sounds like a situation where this could all happen on the database via a single statement.  Then you can use indexing to keep the query fast and avoid having to push data over the wire to and from your database.

Comment: I agree, but you cannot use the database before you have inserted your records (they are coming from a flat file). Of course I could load them into a staging table before but I prefer caching the codes and immediately inserting with the right foreign keys.Otherwise I first have to insert the records (in total 60million) and after that update all 60 million records again (logfile, etc).

Comment: Okay, based on this perhaps you want a SortedList rather than a dictionary.  This puts an index, of a sort (no pun intended), on the list so you can do faster lookups.

Comment: Having them cached in memory is only a good solution if multiple calls during a short period of time is needed. Otherwise creating an index on the table in the DB a querying that would be best.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have enough information to give very prescriptive advice - but there are some general things you should be thinking about.

What types are the time values?  Are you comparing date times or some primitive value (like a time_t).  Think about how your data types affects performance.  Choose the best ones.

Should you really be doing this in memory or should you be putting all these rows in to SQL and letting it be queried on there?  It's really good at that.

But let's stick with what you asked about - in memory searching.

When searching is taking too long there is only one solution - search fewer things.  You do this by partitioning your data in a way that allows you to easily rule out as many nodes as possible with as few operations as possible.

In your case you have two criteria - a code and a date range.  Here are some ideas...

You could partition based on code - i.e.  Dictionary> - if you have many evenly distributed codes your list sizes will each be about N/M in size (where N = total event count and M = number of events).  So a million nodes with ten codes now requires searching 100k items rather than a million.  But you could take that a bit further.  The List could itself be sorted by starting time allowing a binary search to rule out many other nodes very quickly.  (this of course has a trade-off in time building the collection of data).  This should provide very quick

You could partition based on date and just store all the data in a single list sorted by start date and use a binary search to find the start date then march forward to find the code.  Is there a benefit to this approach over the dictionary?  That depends on the rest of your program.  Maybe being an IList is important.  I don't know.  You need to figure that out.

You could flip the dictionary model partition the data by start time rounded to some boundary (depending on the length, granularity and frequency of your events).  This is basically bucketing the data in to groups that have similar start times.  E.g., all the events that were started between 12:00 and 12:01 might be in one bucket, etc.  If you have a very small number of events and a lot of highly frequent (but not pathologically so) events this might give you very good lookup performance.

The point?  Think about your data.  Consider how expensive it should be to add new data and how expensive it should be to query the data.  Think about how your data types affect those characteristics.  Make an informed decision based on that data.  When in doubt let SQL do it for you.